# Python script for delete NaN by null value

Tags: python, pandas

I try to delete NaN value in pyhton, it’s ok but I have one issue in my table in Knime flow :

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name="LAB", usecols = 'A:AB')#, headers=True)


df2 = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)

output_table = df
```

Issue consol : ERROR Python Script (1⇒1)  3:1720     Execute failed: More than one type in column MASTER_REORG_ID. Found float and str

It’s possible to help me ?
Thanks !

Comment: where is your error in the pd.read or the replace

Comment: MASTER_REORG_ID column seems to have a data both as string and as float